# Apache's PidFile directory is removed every boot

Tags: apache-2.4, centos7

Every time the server is rebooted, the directory /run/httpd is removed. /run is a tmpfs filesystem, therefore, mounted in RAM.

/run/httpd is created only during installation. When I start httpd after reboot, the directory isn't recreated.

Server has installed CentOS 7 and the oficial repository Apache package (v. 2.4.6-18).

After Apache install and start, the directory is as bellow:

```
# ls -alR /run/httpd/
/run/httpd/:
total 8
drwx--x---.  3 root   apache  120 Sep 30 08:39 .
drwxr-xr-x. 28 root   root   1020 Sep 30 08:37 ..
-rw-r--r--.  1 root   root      8 Sep 30 08:39 authdigest_shm.2953
drwx------.  2 apache apache   40 Jul 23 10:48 htcacheclean
-rw-r--r--.  1 root   root      5 Sep 30 08:39 httpd.pid
srwx------.  1 apache root      0 Sep 30 08:39 wsgi.2953.0.1.sock

/run/httpd/htcacheclean:
total 0
drwx------. 2 apache apache  40 Jul 23 10:48 .
drwx--x---. 3 root   apache 120 Sep 30 08:39 ..
```

But after reboot:

```
# ls -l /run/httpd
ls: cannot access /run/httpd: No such file or directory
```

And here are the logs when trying to restart Apache:

/var/log/httpd/error_log

```
[Tue Sep 30 09:30:32.310825 2014] [core:notice] [pid 3370] SELinux policy enabled; httpd running as context system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0
[Tue Sep 30 09:30:32.312072 2014] [suexec:notice] [pid 3370] AH01232: suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Tue Sep 30 09:30:32.330380 2014] [auth_digest:notice] [pid 3370] AH01757: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Tue Sep 30 09:30:32.330421 2014] [auth_digest:error] [pid 3370] (2)No such file or directory: AH01762: Failed to create shared memory segment on file /run/httpd/authdigest_shm.3370
[Tue Sep 30 09:30:32.330440 2014] [auth_digest:error] [pid 3370] (2)No such file or directory: AH01760: failed to initialize shm - all nonce-count checking, one-time nonces, and MD5-sess algorithm disabled
[Tue Sep 30 09:30:32.330445 2014] [:emerg] [pid 3370] AH00020: Configuration Failed, exiting
Job for httpd.service failed. See 'systemctl status httpd.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details.
```

/var/log/message

```
Sep 30 08:56:09 brejetuba2 systemd: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
Sep 30 08:56:09 brejetuba2 systemd: httpd.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Job for httpd.service failed. See 'systemctl status httpd.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details.
Sep 30 08:56:09 brejetuba2 systemd: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
Sep 30 08:56:09 brejetuba2 systemd: Unit httpd.service entered failed state.
```

/var/log/audit/audit.log

```
Job for httpd.service failed. See 'systemctl status httpd.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details.
type=SERVICE_START msg=audit(1412083740.602:469): pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:init_t:s0 msg=' comm="httpd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=failed'
```

When I create the directory manually, Apache starts:

```
# mkdir /run/httpd
# systemctl restart httpd
# ls -lRa /run/httpd/
/run/httpd/:
total 8
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root   root  100 Sep 30 09:36 .
drwxr-xr-x. 28 root   root 1020 Sep 30 09:36 ..
-rw-r--r--.  1 root   root    8 Sep 30 09:36 authdigest_shm.3452
-rw-r--r--.  1 root   root    5 Sep 30 09:36 httpd.pid
srwx------.  1 apache root    0 Sep 30 09:36 wsgi.3452.0.1.sock
```

And after reboot, it's gone again.

Any thoughts on why this is happening?

Comment: I ran into an issue very similar to this and the bug that was reported as fixed in 2017 here  https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=54622. I was able to manually delete the _shm.* files that apache was erroring on and get past the issue.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The issue was that, when installing Apache, group *apache* wasn't being created.

```
# systemctl status systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service
systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service - Create Volatile Files and Directories
  Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service; static)
  Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2014-09-30 09:40:30 EDT; 3h 24min ago
Docs: man:tmpfiles.d(5)
      man:systemd-tmpfiles(8)
  Process: 724 ExecStart=/usr/bin/systemd-tmpfiles --create --remove --boot --exclude-prefix=/dev (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
Main PID: 724 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Sep 30 09:40:30 servername systemd-tmpfiles[724]: [/usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/httpd.conf:1] Unknown group 'apache'.
Sep 30 09:40:30 servername systemd-tmpfiles[724]: [/usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/httpd.conf:2] Unknown user 'apache'.
Sep 30 09:40:30 servername systemd[1]: systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Sep 30 09:40:30 servername systemd[1]: Failed to start Create Volatile Files and Directories.
Sep 30 09:40:30 servername systemd[1]: Unit systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service entered failed state.
```

That's because I've a NIS server configured, whith a NIS *apache* user. As it has an *apache* user, Apache installation doesn't create *apache* group. But *apache* group also exists on NIS! Well, NIS is messing up things.

Bottom line is: I have to stop ypbind, install Apache and then restart ypbind (or just create manually a *apache* group in /etc/group).

Answer (score 3):

I had this same problem but with a slightly different solution.

Using [@joaoolavo](https://serverfault.com/users/245917/joaoolavo)'s solution, I tried `systemctl status systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service`:

```
[root@server ~]# systemctl status systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service
● systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service - Create Volatile Files and Directories
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service; static; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
     Docs: man:tmpfiles.d(5)
           man:systemd-tmpfiles(8)
```

Note that Active: inactive (dead).

Restarting systemd-tmpfiles-setup created the files I needed in /run/ , and the status changed to Active: active (exited), although, obviously, httpd (and in my case, postgresql) weren't loaded:

```
[root@server ~]# systemctl start systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service
[root@server ~]# systemctl status systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service
● systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service - Create Volatile Files and Directories
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service; static; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (exited) since Fri 2016-03-18 13:35:36 AEDT; 8s ago
     Docs: man:tmpfiles.d(5)
           man:systemd-tmpfiles(8)
  Process: 2551 ExecStart=/usr/bin/systemd-tmpfiles --create --remove --boot --exclude-prefix=/dev (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 2551 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Mar 18 13:35:36 server.org systemd[1]: Starting Create Volatile Files and Directories...
Mar 18 13:35:36 server.org systemd[1]: Started Create Volatile Files and Directories.
```

Would it survive a reboot?

Yes it does. In fact, reboots now come up as we would expect - all tmpfiles created, httpd and postgresql are also started.

It would seem that `systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service` needs to be in Active state **active (exited)** rather than **inactive (dead)** to work properly after boot.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same solution for my problem as [@datakid](https://serverfault.com/users/173454/datakid) with the difference that after a reboot the `systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service` was dead again.

For my solution you first need to know that I mounted my /var directory on a different disk. And there was the problem. 
My `/etc/fstab` for the `/var` looked like this:

```
/dev/xvdb1 /var ext4 defaults,noatime,_netdev,nofail 0 2
```

So the problem was the _netdev. Because this might be useful for a NFS, where you need a network but not for my case with the `/var`directory

Here's the explanation for _netdev:

> The filesystem resides on a device that requires network access (used to prevent the system from attempting to mount these filesystems until the network has been enabled on the system).

After i removed the _netdev everything was working again, also after reboot

Comment: /run on RHEL systems should be a tmpfs therefore "fixes" which reference /var are a red-herring: